# SSL in Wakanda - Intermediate certificates

Tags: ssl, wakanda

I'm in the process of updating the SSL key/s for a legacy app I'm working on. The Wakanda documentation states that installing the SSL keys is straight forward - put a key.pem and cert.pem in the Certificates directory - but what is required to make an 'intermediate' certificate work along side these?

To expand, I've just updated to a RSA SHA-2 (under SHA-1 Root) SSL Certificate, which requires an intermediate.crt to perform the handshake on all browsers. Yet I can't find any documentation relating to expanding Wakanda so that it can support this. Placing this file in my /etc/ssl/certs folder isn't the solution, as Wakanda isn't using the standard Apache cert directories? Or is there an additional configuration to include this new certificate?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the certificates are in PEM format and place all three files into the Certificates folder like this:

```
Solution\Certificates\key.pem
Solution\Certificates\cert.pem
Solution\Certificates\intermediate.pem
```

Comment: Thanks! I also got a response from our 4D/Wak fella overseas who says you can also concatenate the the three certificates in the same file, cert.pem. I've just set it up your way purely out of those few seconds saved, and worked immediately as well.

Comment: I almost mentioned concatenation but felt it was more error prone so I left it out.

Comment: As an edit to my comment for others in the future, by 'concatenate the three certs', I mean the SSL certificate, the intermediate certificate, and a root certificate (if you have one). The key stays separate, I thought I should clear that up